# Linking more than one button to the same site xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, button, hyperlink, viewcontroller

How do I link a button on Xcode to a website? I have one button that works it is a "buy now" button that redirects to a online shop. I need 3 more of these buttons across my app but it is not letting me control drag to the but of code I already have?

thanks
chelsey

Comment: "I need 3 more of these buttons across my app but it is not letting me to control drag" You mean it's in different view controllers? Then that's normal. What about creating a custom `UIButton` that will handle itself the touch and redirect to wherever you want?

Comment: yes I'm new to doing this and have learnt so far what I have on my own but this I'm struggling with? I'm from webdesign area so its a lot different then a basic hyper link. how can I get all but buttons to link to a website the object when click and dragging shows up as "exit" but on my other view controller where the button links and works it shows up as "view controller"

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is in every class file and the buttons are in add this code

```
@IBAction func toBuyLink(_ sender: Any) { 

    if let url = URL(string: "https://www.store.com/buynow") { //This is an example as I dont know your link. 
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
   }
}
```

This will open your store link in safari (I am guessing this is how you want it) Whenever you press the button.

PLEASE NOTE

You will have to reference the button action in the view class and then add the below code :)

Comment: I have one button working but I'm trying to have the button throughout my app not just on one view controller ?

Comment: I am still not understanding this? I need multiple of buttons to be linked to the same site?one is working but then it won't let me do the same process on the other buttons.... thanks chelsey

Comment: I don’t fully understand what you mean @chelsey mckenzie

Comment: I have 6  pages on my app - 5 of them I need a button that will link to the online shop a "buy now" button I have one of these buttons working but when I repeat the process it doesn't allow me and crashes the system @skyenterprises